# CMAKE share variable between subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to access from `foo` (see below) a variable which is calculated in `bar`. The approach I observed on SO is to add `CACHE INTERNAL` to the `SET`. It works, but I have to invoke the generation of the `GNU Make` files twice. Looks like the variable is not in cache for the first run so, I get just an empty value.

The structure

```
CMakeList.txt (top)--
                    |
                    -- CMakeList.txt (foo)
                    |
                    -- CMakeList.txt (bar)
```

The content
Top CMakeList.txt

```
...
...
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(foo)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(bar)
...
...
```

Foo CMakeList.txt

```
...
...
    TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(MyProject SYSTEM PRIVATE
        ${BarPath}
    )
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Bar include path " ${BarPath})
...
...
```

Bar CMakeList.txt

```
...
...
SET(BarPath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "Path to generated files.")
...
...
```

Then when I run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"` the `MESSAGE` from the Foo's file returns empty `BarPath`. Run it once again and the expected value is populated into variable. Whats wrong?

Comment: Bar gets evaluated after Foo because of the order in Top, so only if you have a chaced result will it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo/CMakeLists.txt` is executed by `cmake` before `Bar/CMakeLists.txt`.

When you first run `cmake`:

1. `${BarPath}` is undefined and `Foo/CMakeLists.txt` prints it as empty.
2. `${BarPath}` is defined and cached by `Bar/CMakeLists.txt`.

When you run it a second time:

3. `${BarPath}` is found in the cache by `Foo/CMakeLists.txt` prints it.
4. `${BarPath}` is redefined and cached by `Bar/CMakeLists.txt`.